# Clicar em qualquer local do <li> e executar o href de <a>

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

E possível visualizar que o `<a>`é clicável ou seja, eu clico nele e ele me redireciona para outro local por exemplo, mas gostaria de saber como faço para que seja possível clicar em qualquer lugar do `<li>` para ocorrer o redirecionamento e não só no `<a>`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> Um </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> Dois </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> Tres </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Não importa em qual local eu clico dentro do `<li>` ele executaria o `href` dentro do `<a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanda o `<a>` para toda a área da `<li>` com o CSS:

```
ul li a{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: gray;
}

ul li a{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="javascript:alert('um')"> Um </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:alert('dois')"> Dois </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:alert('tres')"> Tres </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isso ai funcionou certinho, só tem que tomar cuidado com o padding do <li> e usar padding apenas no <a>, Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o evento onclick na `li`:

```css
 ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align:center;
    }

    ul li {
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    ul li:hover {
      background: gray;
    }
    
    li { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="location.href = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/';"> Um </li>
  <li onclick="location.href = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272339/clicar-em-qualquer-local-do-li-e-executar-o-href-de-a';"> Dois </a> </li>
  <li onclick="location.href = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272336/validar-tamanho-da-senha';"> Tres </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: isso é meio que uma gambiarra né? não está de acordo com a semântica né?

Comment: Não sei, temos  imagem link,  div link e por ai vai. Funciona?

Comment: não estou falando do link em si mas sim da forma de preencher o <li>, vou ver se encontro outro método, que eu use <li> <a> </a> </li> e consiga executar essa tarefa, caso eu não consiga dou certo na sua resposta! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Faça assim: <li onclick="location.href = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/';">click</li>

Comment: O elemento `ul` espera somente `li` como filhos. Qualquer outro elemento quebra a semântica e deixa o HTML inválido conforme a W3C. Embora costuma funcionar devido às implementações atuais dos navegadores, é altamente recomendável que isso seja evitado, visto que os navegadores podem corrigir isso a qualquer momento e que sistema de buscas penalizam a página por não serem os padrões.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, explicação convincente, editei pergunta